# Kaboom - Is there an equivalent of the grounded() attribute for touching a wall?

Tags: javascript, kaboom

I'm trying to make it so that I can have a wall jump in my game, is there a way to check if an object is touching the side of another physics object similar to the .grounded() attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might work:

```js
player.collides(
  'wall', // That's a tag.
  () => {
    // When player collides with anything tagged wall
  }
);
```

Or if you want to manually check on each frame,

```js
player.action(() => {
  if (player.isColliding(wall)) { // wall is a game object this time
    // When player collides with game object wall
  }
});
```

Comment: It looks like my answer is no longer valid due to API changes.